# Fortran: can you explain this formatting string

Tags: formatting, fortran, fortran95

I have a Fortran program which I need to modify, so I'm reading it and trying to understand. Can you please explain what the formatting string in the following statement means:

```
write(*,'(1p,(5x,3(1x,g20.10)))') x(jr,1:ncols)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html

breifly, you are writing three general (g) format floats per line. Each float has a total field width of 20 characters and 10 places to the right of the decimal.  Large magnitude numbers are in exponential form.

The `1x`s are simply added spaces (which could as well have been accomplished by increasing the field width ie, `g21.10` since the numbers are right justified. The `5x` puts an additional 5 spaces at the beginning of each line.

The somewhat tricky thing here is tha lead `1p` which is a scale factor. It causes the mantissa of all exponential form numbers produced by the following `g` format to be multiplied by 10, and the exponent changed accordingly, ie instead of the default,

```
    g17.10  ->  b0.1234567890E+12
```

you get:

```
  1p,g17.10  -> b1.2345678900E+11
```

`b` denotes a blank in the output.  Be sure to allow room for a `-` in your field width count...

for completeness in the case of scale greater than one the number of decimal places is reduced (preserving the total precision) ie,

```
  3p,g17.10  -> b123.45678900E+09  ! note only 8 digits after the decimal
```

that is `1p` buys you a digit of precision over the default, but you don't get any more. Negative scales cost you precision, preserving the 10 digits:

```
    -7p,g17.10  ->  b0.0000000123E+19
```

I should add, the `p` scale factor edit descriptor does something *completely different* on input.  Read the docs...

Comment: Thank you so much for this extensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add slightly to George's answer. Unfortunately this is a very nasty (IMO) part of Fortran. In general, bear in mind that a Fortran format specification is automatically repeated as long as there are values remaining in the input/output list, so it isn't necessary to provide formats for every value to be processed.

#### Scale factors

In the output, all floating point values following *k***P** are multiplied by 10<sup>*k*</sup>. Fields containing exponents (**E**) have their exponent reduced by *k*, unless the exponent format is fixed by using **EN** (engineering) or **ES** (scientific) descriptors. Scaling does not apply to **G** editing, **unless** the value is such that **E** editing is applied. Thus, there is a difference between `(1P,G20.10)` and `(1P,F20.10)`.

#### Grouping

A format like *n*() repeats the descriptors within parentheses *n* times before proceeding.

Comment: Also, I echo George's recommendation of reading documentation on this. [IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/topic/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/iof.html) has pretty extensive information on this topic.

Comment: Now that `EN` and `ES` are available, I no longer use `G`.  IMO, prior to that, it was useful to modify `E`.   `G` can be really dangerous; as mentioned in the other answer, its behavior is different between output and input!

Comment: @M.S.B. I think you could wallpaper a house with a printout of all the format descriptors, not to mention all the parameters of `open`, `read` and `write`... I love Fortran, but not this part :P