# Fortran format 1P10E11.3

Tags: format, fortran, exponential

Does anyone know what this format line means in fortran:

```
FORMAT(1x,F7.0,2x,1P10E11.3)
```

I know the first part is one repetition of float number but I don't understand how many exponential data points are read in the second part and what that P is for.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22350099/3157076.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `P` format shifts the decimal point.  The behavior is different on input and output.  On output, applied to an `E` format, it shifts the decimal point of the value before the exponent and changes the values of the exponent such that the value of the number is unchanged.   If plain `E` would output 0.123E+3, `1PE` will output 1.230E+2.  On input it changes the value read -- use with great caution or not at all. Another "gotcha" is that P stays in effect for the rest of the format, until another P specifier appears in the format, e.g., `0P` to reset.  One of the newer `G`, `ES` or `EN` formats are generally better than the combination of `P` and `E`.